# How to override label visibility?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want hide a label visibility by another content, suppose I have a GroupBox which contains a DataGrid:

```
<GroupBox>
    <DataGrid x:Name="Dt">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="home" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</GroupBox>
```

I want insert a `Label` which appear only when I hide the `DataGrid`, so I tried a simple `StackPanel`:

```
<GroupBox>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <DataGrid x:Name="Dt">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="home" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Label Content="Foo" />
  </StackPanel>
</GroupBox>
```

so I tried to set the visibility of `DataGrid` behind code, like:

```
Dt.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

this will hide the `DataGrid` but the main problem is the label, in fact the label is even visible, also if the `Dt` is visibile.

How can I display the label only when the DataGrid is hidden?

Comment: You could bind the visibility of the label to datagrid visibility and use a converter that switch the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Grid` panel and place Label before DataGrid. They are positioned in the same  grid cell and this will ensure that Label is covered by DataGrid when it is visible.

```
<GroupBox>
  <Grid>
    <Label Content="Foo" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="Dt">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="home" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
  </Grid>
</GroupBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can default the Label's visibility to Hidden and in the code behind, when the DataGrid is hidden in whatever method you adjust that, you set the visibility of the label to Visible

XAML:

```
<GroupBox>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <DataGrid x:Name="Dt">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="home" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Label Content="Foo" Visibility="Hidden" x:Name="fooLabel" />
  </StackPanel>
</GroupBox>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void yourMethod(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Dt.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    fooLabel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could apply a `Style` to the `Label` with a `DataTrigger` that binds to the `Visibility` property of the `DataGrid`:

```
<GroupBox>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <DataGrid x:Name="Dt" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="home" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Label Content="Foo">
            <Label.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Label">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=Dt}" Value="Visible">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Label.Style>
        </Label>
    </StackPanel>
</GroupBox>
```

Using this XAML only approach you could bind to any property of the `DataGrid`. You could for example bind to the `HasItems` property and only display the `Label` when the `DataGrid` is empty. No converters needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could bind the visibility of the label to datagrid visibility and use a converter that *switch the value*:

```
<GroupBox>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
         <local:VisibilityInverter x:key="VisInverter"/>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <DataGrid x:Name="Dt">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="home" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Label Content="Foo" Visibility="{Binding Path=Visibility, ElementName=Dt, Converter={StaticResource VisInverter}}" />
  </StackPanel>
</GroupBox>
```

Here the **converter**:

```
public class VisibilityInverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return Visibility.Hidden;

        if (value == Visibility.Visible)
            return Visibility.Hidden;

        return Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, ultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Visibility property of the Datagrid element and assign to the label when grid is visible label also will be visible.

```
<Label Content="Foo" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Dt, Path=Visibility}" />
```